# T-SQL CTE + classic asp - which CommandType to use?

Tags: t-sql, asp-classic, common-table-expression

I have a CTE statement. When I try to execute in with classic asp the parameter is not replaced correctly:

```
Set cmd=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = objConnection
cmd.CommandText =   " my CTE is here"

cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'adCmdUnspecified,adCmdText,adCmdTable,adCmdStoredProc,adCmdUnknown,adCmdFile,adCmdTableDirect

Set objParam = cmd.CreateParameter(, adBigInt , adParamInput ,8,CLng(MyParameter))
cmd.Parameters.Append objParam
```

When I get the final statement the "?" is not replace in the statement and it gives me error.

I try with each command type but no results.

Comment: And the error is....? Have you considered a stored procedure instead?

Comment: Yes, this is a customization and store procedure can not be apply. The error is Incorrect syntax near '='. because in the statement I have "... = ?" instead '... = 1000 ' - the parameter is not replaced.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: You could use a named parameter instead of a question mark, like @SomeParameter, and then your code would be cmd.CreateParameter("SomeParameter", ...)

Comment: @Joro, your interpretation of the error message is incorrect. ADO does not replace parameter placeholders with parameter values.  Instead, it sends the SQL statements (with ?s) to the DBMS along with the parameter values, and the DBMS will take care of the rest.  There is some other syntax error in your SQL statement.

Comment: @Cheran Shunmugavel, yes you are completely right. There was a silly syntax error that cause this "error message".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by foolish syntax error in the "CommandText" string.